# startx fails fedora 23

Tags: fedora, x11, xorg, x-server, sddm

Under Fedora 23, I cannot start the X server by normal means. How can I fix this?

I am aware that there's no shortage of similar problems reported over the years, but so far none of those fixes have worked. So, here's me asking.

I'm running fedora 23 with kde. The login screen shows properly ( so I think this isn't a driver issue), along with the username and password prompt. Curiously, the dropdown menu for the session type has no entries. After entering any username/password combination and hitting enter or the 'login' button, nothing happens.

Then I use ctrl-alt-f5 to pause the X server. `startx` produces:

```
xauth:  file /mnt/driveB/mrkelly/.serverauth.2784 does not exist


X.Org X Server 1.18.1
Release Date: 2016-02-08
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System:  4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64 
Current Operating System: Linux action-jackson.stanford.edu 4.4.6-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 22:10:37 UTC 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.6-300.fc23.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_action--jackson-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora_action-jackson/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_action-jackson/boot rd.lvm.lv=fedora_action-jackson/root rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Build Date: 09 March 2016  05:53:36AM
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.18.1-3.fc23 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/mnt/driveB/mrkelly/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Mar 30 16:19:20 2016
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
(II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
pci id for fd 9: 102b:0532, driver (null)
EGL_MESA_drm_image required.
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Alternatively, from `xinit`:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the Fedora Project support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
No protocol specified
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable
xinit: server error
```

The mentioned log file at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` shows identical information.
I've removed .Xauthority and reinstalled xorg-x11-xserver, and I've rebooted the machine multiple times.

The two questions here (http://wiki.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages/#index5h2) woudl at first seem to apply. Vis-a-vis "Server is already active for display 0", there is no /tmp/.X0-lock, or an .X0-lock file anywhere on the system. `startx -- :1` fails thus :

```
xauth:  file /mnt/driveB/mrkelly/.serverauth.3622 does not exist


X.Org X Server 1.18.1
Release Date: 2016-02-08
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System:  4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64 
Current Operating System: Linux action-jackson.stanford.edu 4.4.6-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 22:10:37 UTC 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.6-300.fc23.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_action--jackson-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora_action-jackson/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_action-jackson/boot rd.lvm.lv=fedora_action-jackson/root rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Build Date: 09 March 2016  05:53:36AM
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.18.1-3.fc23 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/mnt/driveB/mrkelly/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Mar 30 16:38:32 2016
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
(II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
pci id for fd 9: 102b:0532, driver (null)
EGL_MESA_drm_image required.
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

The next heading "I keep getting the message: "Cannot establish any listening sockets..."", suggests that I run `netstat -ln`. It's not clear to me what I **do** with the information there, but here is the output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3838            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20048           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33654           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60698           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::34665                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::20048                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::37366                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56603           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:64711           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 171.65.15.255:137       0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 171.65.12.204:137       0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 171.65.15.255:138       0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 171.65.12.204:138       0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:653             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:659           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20048           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35282           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38319           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::57722                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                               
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::653                  :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::20048                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::37129                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::43415                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::48357                :::*                               
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7          
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1281     /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25118    /var/run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     37072    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25125    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27959    /var/lib/gssproxy/default.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25134    /var/run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27960    /run/gssproxy.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25149    /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18504    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25144    @ISCSID_UIP_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     23891    /tmp/sddm-authe39d3035-97b2-4350-af12-23c7809a9fc8
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34161    /var/run/abrt/abrt.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     33151    /run/samba/nmbd/unexpected
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27029    /var/run/NetworkManager/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27287    /run/user/989/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17588    /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27069    /var/run/NetworkManager/private-dhcp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25113    @ISCSIADM_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     37073    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     17628    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17637    /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     37096    /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25580    /tmp/drozIR/s
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     29250    @/tmp/dbus-6AiboYp1lV
Active Bluetooth connections (only servers)
Proto  Destination       Source            State         PSM DCID   SCID      IMTU    OMTU Security
Proto  Destination       Source            State     Channel
```

UPDATES:
1) per @mattdm, This is from the Fedora 21 workstation KDE spin, upgraded to Fedora 23. `kdeinit5` also fails, yes. And again, the option to start a KDE session isn't available from the login window.

Comment: Just to confirm: a) this is with the KDE spin, not KDE added to Fedora Workstation or otherwise, and b) the problem isn't just with startx, but that your KDE session won't start from sddm, right?

Comment: Wrote answers to @mattdm in original post.

Comment: Given the lack of answers, I'm now switching the machine over to gdm. I'd really like to return to sddm/kde if possible, but the need to get actual work done supersedes that preference.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I don't really know much about sddm.